# Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn not creating cookie

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-web-api2

The following Code is not creating .ASPNET Cookie, I am using this code in WebAPI custom login method

```
  //TODO Validate Credential
  var claims = new List<Claim>();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "ABCDE"));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "ABCDE@EFGH.com"));

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            var authmgr = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            authmgr.SignIn(id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you make sure you added the following to your App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs ?

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
   });
}
```

Check out Brock Allen's primer -

http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that can cause this is having CookieSecure set to Always, at least when debugging. When I took that out I got a cookie, and when it was there I got no cookie. In the Startup.Configuration (previously ConfigureAuth) method:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    //CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Index"),
    SlidingExpiration = true
});
```